# wxDataViewCtrl in wxSmith palette

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm using Code:Blocks with wxSmith to build some small programs.
I want to play with wxDataViewCtrl and wxDataViewModel but I cannot find the control in the wxSmith palette.

I've tried to add it manually with some code but I've just ended messing up the frame layout... I wonder how can I have this control managed by wxSmith.

update:
I was able to use custom control and put it inside the wxDataViewCtrl. That was easy. The difficult part was to find information about this custom control.

Searching the web I've found nothing interesting.